# Run a function in backend when clicking a button in frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am new to web development, I need some help guys :
I have this function classification that takes a file path as an argument and does some stuff and saves a JSON file

```
talk2flask.classification(file_path);
```

And I have this button "parse" that opens another page '/questions' that will load text from the Jason file and display it

```
Parsing = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', null);
  this.props.history.push('/questions');

}
```

```
                  <TableCell align="center">
                        <Button
                      className="button_style"
                      variant="outlined"
                      color="primary"
                      size="small"
                      onClick={this.Parsing}
                    >
                      parse 
                      </Button>
         
                  </TableCell>
```

[enter image description here][1]
Now as you can see in the image I have many items ,  each time I click the button parse I want the function classification to run with that item path as argument to generate the appropriate json file

I understand that I have to use axios to do but I came nowhere to doing it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S74V.png

Comment: We're going to need some more information if you want a helpful answer.

Comment: Axios is a client-side (in your web browser) library for making dynamic web requests.
Using this library (or any other web requests library) you can make a web request (aka "call" your web server) and get it to do some work. 
We cannot provide much help without an understanding of what your backend technology (your server) is

Comment: what do you mean by backend technology ? ( I new to this sorry)

Comment: You've repeated the details in the question but haven't provided anything useful.

Comment: Is your backend server running on PHP, Ruby, Python, Node.JS, Go, Rust, C, C++, or ASP.NET?

Comment: backend server running on Nodejs

Comment: Not sure if I can add an image link, but here's a quick overview of how this should be working. https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*rv-jJklXZCZO8U6svKmIYg.png

Comment: Node.JS will "run" your Javascript, but won't expose the functionality over HTTP (web requests) without you wrapping it in an API of some sort.
The common example would be to use the Express framework for Node.JS. Use this framework to serve your functionality over an endpoint.
Code e.g.

app.get('/classification', (req, res) => {
  // Here you can run your code
  const results = talk2flask.classification(req.params.path);
  // Now we return the result to the client
  res.send(results);
})

Then on the client, you make a web request to https://my_server/classification?path=myPath

Comment: this is I wanted to know if you could just explain how to to make the web request on the client side

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (as far as I can tell) is that you have some JS code for Node.JS but not a way to "serve" the functionality it provides to your client application.

To expose the functionality to your client application (your web page) you need to host an API for your client to call.

## Example

There are a lot of way to do this, but here's an example.

### Express.js

Using the [express framework](https://expressjs.com/) you can serve your functionality.
Install it by running `npm i express --save` in your project directory.

#### Usage

Now to use it, in your code you can do the following:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/classification', (req, res) => {
  // Get the file path from the client's request
  const filePath = req.query.path;
  // Run the classifier here
  const result = talk2flask.classification(filePath);
  // Respond to the client here
  res.send(result);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Please bear in mind that accepting the file path from a user is quite dangerous, as they could potentially provide any file path they want (that's bad) rather than the one's you expect. You should put in some protections there to ensure only the files you want are accessed.

#### Client-side usage

The client needs to make a web request to your new endpoint giving the required file path:
`http://<your_host>/classification?path=filepath.json`

Lookup how to use Axios, and this is a simple GET request.
With Axios included in your page, it should be as simple as this:

```js
axios.get(url).then(response => {
  // Use the response here
  console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {
  // Handle errors here
  console.log(error)
})
```